# Find outlet of $x^3y-x^2-9xy+2x+8=0$

Tags: calculus

Find outlet of: $$x^3y-x^2-9xy+2x+8=0$$

I keep getting $y'= \frac{-3x^2y+2x+9y{\color{red}{-2}}}{x^3-9x}$ as a solution, but it's not correct, the book says the solution is: $y'= \frac{-3x^2y+2x+9y{\color{red}{+2}}}{x^3-9x}$; is it possible that they made a mistake?

Comment: Aren't you missing something? Shouldn't that expression be equal to zero or anything else?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I'll correct it right away.

Comment: It appears that the word 'outlet' means set to $0$ and find the implicit derivative of $y,$ which should be written as $y'$

Comment: okay, I corrected that as well, but what I really want to know is why there is +2 (in numerator) and why I always get -2 ??

Comment: @user114141 : What's "outlet"?????? Someone deciphered your question, but please fix it for future readers' sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once everything is differentiated, you should have
$$3x^2y+x^3y^{\prime} -2x-9y-9xy^{\prime}+2=0$$
Solving for $y^{\prime}$ gives you
$$y^{\prime} = \frac{-3x^2y+2x+9y-2}{x^3-9x}$$
so your answer is correct (and thus the book is wrong).  The book's answer would be correct if the original problem was to differentiate
$$x^3y-x^2-9xy\color{red}{-}2x+8 = 0.$$